# Request URL cambiada en el fetch con SSL

Tags: ssl, certificado-ssl

He puesto ssl a el servidor que tengo y sin SSL todo bien coge bien la direccion, pero cuando activo el ssl me cambia la direccion a `/apu` y no `/api`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saben a que se puede deber?

EDITO: Al final resulto ser las DNS de cloudflare no se propagaron por la parte del frontend. Simplemente me toco esperar 1 dia, pero fue un dia de mucha incertidumbre.

Comment: Revisa el código, dudo mucho que un SSL altere peticiones al servidor, a menos que haya algún interceptor del request y lo cambie. Por otro lado, lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final resulto ser las DNS de cloudflare no se propagaron por la parte del frontend. Simplemente me toco esperar 1 dia, pero fue un dia de mucha incertidumbre.